# ZFS: Rollback snapshot but keep newer snapshots

Tags: rollback, snapshot, zfs

I have following ZFS Snapshots:

```
data/server/dev1@snap1
data/server/dev1@snap2
data/server/dev1@snap3
```

If i want to rollback to `snap1`, i would do the following:

```
zfs rollback data/server/dev1@snap1
```

but ZFS returns:

```
more recent snapshots or bookmarks exist
use '-r' to force deletion..
```

I know there is the possibility to simply copy the files out of `/data/server/dev1/.zfs/snapshot/snap1` into `/data/server/dev1` but that takes much longer than a `zfs rollback`.

Is there a way to do the rollback **AND** keep the newer snapshots `snap2` & `snap3`?

**Update 21/11/2016**

It looks like there is a way to do this. I read about working with `zfs promote` and `zfs clone` but I could not figure out how it exactly works.

Comment: The only ways I can think of would involve cloning the snapshot you want to roll back to.  See this zfsonlinux thread:  http://list.zfsonlinux.org/pipermail/zfs-discuss/2015-July/022805.html

Comment: Thanks. How is that done? I can create a clone with `zfs clone data/server/dev1@snap1 data/server/dev1-temp` for example. How can I rollback from that? A simple `zfs rollback` returns `operation not applicable to datasets of this type`

Comment: This question should be on [sf] as it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your comment is pretty close to getting you what you want.  However, you could rename the file system before cloning then clone to the name of the original file system.  For example:

```
zfs rename data/server/dev1 data/server/dev2 
zfs clone data/server/dev2@snap1 data/server/dev1
```

You don't have to worry about promoting until you need to delete data/server/dev2@snap1

The zfs man page has a more complete example that may or may not address your needs more specifically:

> The  following commands illustrate how to test out changes to a file
>   system, and then replace the original file system with the changed
>   one, using clones, clone promotion, and renaming:

```
     # zfs create pool/project/production
       populate /pool/project/production with data
     # zfs snapshot pool/project/production@today
     # zfs clone pool/project/production@today pool/project/beta
     make changes to /pool/project/beta and test them
     # zfs promote pool/project/beta
     # zfs rename pool/project/production pool/project/legacy
     # zfs rename pool/project/beta pool/project/production
     once the legacy version is no longer needed, it can be destroyed
     # zfs destroy pool/project/legacy
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution seems to work. Meanwhile, I managed it by copying the files. As it's already used in a script on production environment, I first have to take a further look at it.

Comment: Glad it seems to work...good luck with the production environment implementation!